# Convergence of $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \ln\left (1 + \frac{1}{n} \right )$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \ln \left (1 + \frac{1}{n} \right )$$

I am trying to show that is expression converges. This is in the form of a partial sum, so this expression converges if the following converges

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right )$$

I feel like this must be a known result, I am just blanking on how to do it. My usual convergence criteria don't seem to be uselful, besides perhaps this one, about integrability that I'm still not so sure how to use.

For a positive, continuous and decreasing function ( which is what we have ), $\forall x \ge N$, and for $f(n)=a_n$, $\forall n \ge N$, then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\ \text{converges} \iff \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_N^n f(x)\,dx \ \text{exists}$$

In my course we are just getting into integrals so I'm not quite sure how to show that the limit of this integral exists. Is this the right direction to go or should it be simpler to show the convergence of this series?

**Update**

This was a sub-question to a larger question, which was whether or not the following converges to zero or not. Again, we have a zero times infinity situation. I was hoping just the main term converged.

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N \ln \left (1 + \frac{1}{n} \right )$$

Comment: The sum diverges. In particular you have $\sum_{n=1}^N \ln (1 + 1/n) = \ln (N+1).$  Is it possible you've transcribed the problem incorrectly?

Comment: @MichaelLugo no it is correct, I guess I should have written that I was hoping it converged, but now I see that it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove divergence, note that

$$\ln(1 + 1/n) = \int_1^{1+1/n} \frac{dt}{t}  \geqslant \frac{1/n}{1+1/n} = \frac{1}{n+1}$$

**Regarding the update:**

If $a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ then it follows that $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N a_n \to 0 $ as $N \to \infty$.  In this case $a_n = \ln(1+1/n) \to 0 $.

For proof note that for any $\epsilon> 0$ there exists $M$ such that $|a_n| < \epsilon$ for $n > M$ and

$$\left|\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \right| \leqslant \left|\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^M a_n \right|+ \left|\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=M+1}^N a_n \right| \leqslant \frac{1}{N} \left|\sum_{n=1}^M a_n \right|+ \frac{N-M}{N}\epsilon$$

Thus,

$$0 \leqslant \liminf_{N \to \infty}\left|\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \right| \leqslant \limsup_{N \to \infty}\left|\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \right| < \epsilon,$$

which implies since $\epsilon$ can be arbitrarily close to $0$,

$$\lim_{N \to \infty}\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n = 0$$

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question, which gives a little off-shoot.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind: Reply to the update has been added above. I should add that it is usually best to post another question when making such a change.

Comment: If $a_n \to a$ then $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \to a$ is a well-known result.

Comment: This is great, the only question is about your proof that $\sum \ln(1+1/n) \to 0$. It seems you are assuming integrability of the function to do that? I have been trying to show $\sum \ln(1+1/n) \to 0$ by the fact ( I think ) that it is bounded, $\ln(1+1/n) < 1/n$ for positive $n$. Then I know I can prove that $\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum \frac{1}{n} = 0$. However the proof that $\ln(1+1/n)<1/n$ is proving harder than I originally thought.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind: I'm not saying anywhere that $\sum \ln(1+1/n) \to 0$.  All answers here have proved that the series diverges.  It is true that the sequence $\ln(1+1/n)$ converges to $0$.  It is relatively easy to prove that $\ln(1+x) < x$ regardless of your definition for $\ln$.  From the integral we have $\ln(1+x) = \int_1^{1+x} \frac{dt}{t} < \frac{1+x-1}{1} = x$.  Defining $\ln$ as the inverse to $x \mapsto e^x$ just use the fact that $e^x  \geqslant 1 +x$ and take the logarithm of both sides.

Comment: Thanks very much for you time here. Still a lot of these techniques I need to learn. This is all really helpful.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

But, the aforementioned sum diverges.

For $N$ large enough $\ln(1+\frac{1}{N}) \ge \frac{1}{4N}$ [work out the Taylor expansion to see for yourself; $\ln(1+a) \ge a-a^2/2$], and $\sum_{N} \frac{1}{4N}$ diverges.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the question if you'd like to have a look.

Answer (score 1):

hint :

$\ln(1+1/n)= \ln((n+1)/n)= \ln(n+1)-\ln(n)$ .. the sum telescopes

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln\frac21+\ln\frac32+\ln\frac43+\cdots\ln\frac{N+1}N=\ln\frac{2\cdot3\cdot4\cdots(N+1)}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots N}=\ln(N+1)$$

leaves no doubt about convergence.